# Could i use a drawer within an overlay modal?

Tags: modal, drawer

I'm prototyping a candidate selection application for a job agency. The client needs a module in which they can filter to search for the right candidates for a job. When they click on a candidate in the list, an overlay modal pops up with all details on that candidate (there are a lot) + an action module in which an agent can call or mail the candidate in real time and track what's been discussed. The modal already displays a lot, but the client also wants to display the history of that candidate, useful as context when calling the candidate. I would like to display the history's information right into the modal itself but it's too crammed with other info as it is and an agent won't need it all the time. I was thinking of displaying this info through a drawer within the modal but it feels like cramming too many patterns into one functionality. I can design it as an accordeon pattern but that's basically the same behaviour (info sliding open)

The other option would be when the agent clicks on a candidate from the list, instead of having an overlay modal, the agent would drill down to another page. But an overlay modal feels better since you focus the agents' attention to the task.

I was looking up info on the subject but can't seem to find a lot. What is your opinion?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Modals are used when you need to show information in context, they are usually concise and require an action. https://uxplanet.org/best-practices-for-modals-overlays-dialog-windows-c00c66cddd8c

The best would be to have a dedicated page where the agent can take the time to review and you have more breathing space for the amount of information. The accordion sounds ideal on that page too.

In terms of context there is no gain in maintaining the list of candidate on the background of the modal. If the user scenario is that they will need to go through several profiles then the best would be to have a button 'Review Next Candidate' on the dedicated page so they don't need to constantly go back to the list of candidates.

Comment: Hi Taly, thanks for your feedback, it's valuable. Indeed i have foreseen a 'previous' and 'next' button to review other candidates without the need of going back to the list. I think I'll choose for the option where the agent drills down to another page, allowing breathing space and possibilities to insert drawer patterns if needed. Thx